# WPF SyntaxHighlightBox Aurelion

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, syntax, controls

currently I'm trying to implement the SyntaxHighlightBox from Aurelion ([link to project page](https://syntaxhighlightbox.codeplex.com/)) but on this line I get a KeyNotFound exception:

```
 box.CurrentHighlighter = HighlighterManager.Instance.Highlighters["VDHL"];
```

I've imported the .xml file into my project as a ressource and the filename is VDHL.xml. When I tried to load the .xml file via a simple XmlDocument it failed also.
What's the problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation (https://syntaxhighlightbox.codeplex.com/documentation) you have to grab the source, then add your .xml definitions to the **Resources** folder, and ensure that they are built as **Resource**.

I also had to fix the *HightlightManager* class, because it is hardcoded to read resources (including the **syntax.xsd**) from the original assembly. The modified code that works for me is:

```
        //var gfdgd = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/AurelienRibon.Ui.SyntaxHighlightBox;component/resources/syntax.xsd"));
        //var schemaStream = gfdgd.Stream;
        var schemaStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/resources/syntax.xsd")).Stream;
```